# How to do an one way anova with all columns of data fame?

Tags: r, anova

I want to do an ANOVA test with my abundance data of different stations, I want to know what is the correct way to write the script because all examples with aov function are related to a formula but I do not be sure that this formula takes account all columns comparing their means.

The following data are a single example of the way that I use to try to do the test. But there are is not a categorical variable in the columns, for this reason, I am sure that this way is wrong.

Thanks for your help

```
set.seed(200)
D <- data.frame(a=sample(15),b=sample(15), c=sample(15))

A<-aov(a~c, data = D)
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to [reshape the `data.frame` from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format).

The following uses an external package, `reshape2`, to reshape the data from wide to long format.

```
molten <- reshape2::melt(D)
head(molten)

model <- lm(value ~ variable, data = molten)
anova(model)
```